# Visual Basic 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: vb.net

I'm working at a typing program.

After a bit of work i got this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsApplication14.exe
>
> Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub
    
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication14.Form1
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim text As String
        text = TextBox1.Text
        If text = ("") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Gelieve text in te vullen")
        End If

        Dim letter As Char
        letter = text.Substring(0, 1)

        If letter = (" ") Then
            TextBox2.Text = "space"
            TextBox1.ReadOnly = (True)
        Else
            TextBox2.Text = letter
            TextBox1.ReadOnly = (True)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = (" ")
        TextBox1.ReadOnly = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
        Dim inputletter As Char
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim c As String
        Dim d As Char

        c = TextBox3.Text
        a = c.Length() - 1

        If a > -1 Then
            inputletter = c.Substring(a, 1)
            d = Text.Substring(0, 1)
            If d = inputletter Then
                TextBox1.Text.Trim(d)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        TextBox3.Text = (" ")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to work. You are checking if the user entered anything in the textbox, then if he/she didn't you are showing a error-message and just continuing in the program. One way to solve this is by adding a `Exit Sub` statement after your messagebox to make sure the executing sub ends immediately.

```
    Dim text As String
    text = TextBox1.Text
    If text = ("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Gelieve text in te vullen")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim letter As Char
    letter = text.Substring(0, 1)
```